Check many values are not equal in a single statement
I'm creating a constraint in a table so that none of 8 columns must be equal to each other.
I wanted to do it like this:
alter table mytable
    add constraint no_duplicate_values
        check (col_1 <> col_2 <> col__3 <> col__4 <> col__5 <> col__6 <> col__7 <> col__8);

But of course this doesn't work because <> only accepts two operands, left and right.
Is there an elegant, single-statement alternative that's equivalent?

This indicates that it would probably be better to have a table design with rows instead of the columns. Then you'd only need a unique constraint.

Sounds like a broken data model

Important note: This answer assumes you can't fix your current table design (which would be cleaner as pointed out by Thorsten) and it also assumes you don't simply want to use a generic function as proposed in this answer. If at least one of these two assumptions is wrong, stop reading here and go one of the two other ways.
Ok, I don't know why, but let's say if you really want to keep your current design and to urgently use a check constraint with direct logic in it and not with a function call, then let's continue:
A standard way to check whether multiple columns contain the same value is to make the column's values an array and then check if it contains duplicates using  intarray. This extension provides the two functions SORT and UNIQ for arrays, so the combination of them tells us if all values in the array are unique.
Following query will only show those rows of your table where no same value appears in different columns:
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE
  SORT(ARRAY[col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8]) = 
  UNIQ(SORT(ARRAY[col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8]));

And of course, you can define this condition as a check constraint:
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ADD CONSTRAINT no_duplicate_values
    CHECK (
      SORT(ARRAY[col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8]) = 
      UNIQ(SORT(ARRAY[col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8])));

See on this sample fiddle that it works as expected.
Of course, it is a bit clunky to use an extension and to build an array in a constraint. That's why I wrote the note on top of this answer.

To do that you need to use logical AND operator. There is no elegant way BTW, as far as I know. Could you try this one:
       CHECK (
        col_1 <> col_2 AND
        col_1 <> col_3 AND
        col_1 <> col_4 AND
        col_1 <> col_5 AND
        col_1 <> col_6 AND
        col_1 <> col_7 AND
        col_1 <> col_8 AND
        col_2 <> col_3 AND
        col_2 <> col_4 AND
        col_2 <> col_5 AND
        col_2 <> col_6 AND
        col_2 <> col_7 AND
        col_2 <> col_8 AND
        col_3 <> col_4 AND
        col_3 <> col_5 AND
        col_3 <> col_6 AND
        col_3 <> col_7 AND
        col_3 <> col_8 AND
        col_4 <> col_5 AND
        col_4 <> col_6 AND
        col_4 <> col_7 AND
        col_4 <> col_8 AND
        col_5 <> col_6 AND
        col_5 <> col_7 AND
        col_5 <> col_8 AND
        col_6 <> col_7 AND
        col_6 <> col_8 AND
        col_7 <> col_8
    )


I would suggest a simple helper function for a more or less generic solution.
create or replace function row_unique(jr jsonb) returns boolean language sql as 
$$
 select count(value) = count(distinct value) from jsonb_each_text(jr);
$$;

and then
alter table mytable add constraint no_duplicate_values
check (row_unique(to_jsonb(mytable)));

Demo
However, as Thorsten Kettner comments, it may be worth revisiting your data design.
